# lme4: expand single verts?

Tags: r, lme4

This seems like it should be simple, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

If I have a formula with random effects with double verts indicating that the random slopes and intercepts are uncorrelated, I can use `lme4`'s `expandDoubleVerts()` function to expand the random effects into separate terms.

```r
> f <- y ~ x * w + (1 + x * w || z)
> expandDoubleVerts(f)
y ~ x * w + ((1 | z) + (0 + x | z) + (0 + w | z) + (0 + x:w | z))
```

Can I do something similar for formulas with correlated random slopes and intercepts to get something like this?

```r
> f <- y ~ x * w + (1 + x * w | z)
> expandSingleVerts(f)
y ~ x * w + (1 + x + w + x:w | z)
```

There is no function named `expandSingleVerts`, but something like that would be what I want. If there's something more general that would just take a language object like `x * w` and expand it to `x + w + x:w`, that would work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what format you need the results in, I would start with

```r
tt <- attr(terms(~x*w), "term.labels")
res <- paste(tt, collapse = "+")
```

This gets you as far as "x+w+x:w".  The hard part may be converting from whatever you start with and getting back to some kind of language object. e.g., if you start with `qq <- quote(x*w)`, then `bquote(~.(qq))` will get you to `~x+w`.  `parse(text = res)` will get you `expression(x + w + x:w)`.

- [this file](https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/blob/master/glmmTMB/R/reformulas.R) has a lot of machinery for processing formulas
- the reason that there's no machinery for expanding the *terms* of the random effect (i.e. the stuff on the left side of the bar in `(x*w|g)`) is that in processing mixed-model formulas we can usually pass that component straight to `model.matrix()` rather than expanding it ourselves

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Ben Bolker's answer, I've been able to do the following to get the formula with the effects expanded in the single (and double) vert terms.

Here's what I came up with in the end:

```r
library(lme4) # used for `findbars`, `nobars`
# note that this will expand both single and double vert terms,
# because `findbars` expands the double verts 
expandVerts <- function(formula) {
    bars <- findbars(formula)
    groups <- lapply(bars, \(x) x[[3]])
    # found looking in the lme4 source
    bars <- lapply(
        bars, 
        \(x) {
            eval(
                substitute(~ foo, list(foo = x[[2]])),
                envir = environment(formula)
            )
        }
    )
    terms <- lapply(bars, terms)
    intercepts <- lapply(terms, \(x) attr(x, 'intercept'))
    # thanks to Ben Bolker!
    terms <- lapply(terms, \(x) attr(x, 'term.labels'))
    expanded <- mapply(
        \(intercept, term, group) {
            group.sep <- ifelse(length(group), ' | ', '')
            intercept.sep <- ifelse(length(term), ' + ', '')
            paste0(
                '(', 
                    intercept, intercept.sep,
                    paste(term, collapse = ' + '), group.sep,
                    group,
                ')'
            )
        },
        intercepts,
        terms, 
        groups
    )
    
    nobar <- deparse1(nobars(formula))
    nobar.sep <- ifelse(length(expanded), ' + ', '')
    reconstructed <- as.formula(
        paste0(nobar, nobar.sep, paste(expanded, collapse = ' + ')),
        env = environment(formula)
    )
    reconstructed
}
```

Then:

```r
> f <- y ~ x * w + (1 + x * w | z)
> expandVerts(f)
y ~ x * w + (1 + x + w + x:w | z)

> f <- y ~ x * w + (1 + x * w | z) + (1 + x * w || a)
> expandVerts(f)
y ~ x * w + (1 + x + w + x:w | z) + (1 | a) + (0 + x | a) + (0 + 
    w | a) + (0 + x:w | a)
```

And, as a sanity check:

```r
> f <- y ~ x * w
> expandVerts(f)
y ~ x * w
```